# How to disable the up/down buttons within the QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a QDoubleSpinBox in QT. I would like to conditionally disable the step up and/or down buttons. I am not sure how to do this.

I saw that in the QAbstractSpinBox there is a flag called StepEnabledFlag. But i am not sure how to set that.

Can  anybody help me out with this.

Thanks
Arjun

Answer (score 4):

Use `QAbstractSpinBox::setButtonSymbols()`. You can set one or both of the arrow buttons to be disabled.

Documentation reference: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qabstractspinbox.html#buttonSymbols-prop.

Comment: Actually, set button symbols allows you to choose between up and down arrow buttons, plus and minus buttons, or no buttons at all. It doesn't let you individually enable and disable them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a QDoubleSpinBox subclass with a custom implementation of the step enabled function. (http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qabstractspinbox.html#stepEnabled)